# Comparing indexes in arrays/vectors

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I just completed a project through Codecademy, and I couldn't for the life of me figure it out. I went and looked at the example solution and it contained code that I didn't even know you could do and I cannot figure out how it works.

There is a nested for loop, and the user takes advantage of adding the indexes together?? Or is comparing them?? I've just never seen it done, to be quite honest and I have looked for an explanation of what exactly is happening and I can't find one.

`

```
  for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i) {
        
    int match = 0;
        
    for (int j = 0; j < word.size(); ++j) {
    
      if (text[i+j] == word[j]) {
        
        ++match;
          
      }
    
    }
```

`

The project was a C++ program where you had to bleep a word out of any phrase that was input into the program. I just don't understand what "text[i+j]" accomplishes? How do you add two indexes together in a for loop?? Does it add?? Does it compare?? But comparison doesn't make much sense to me either??

Here is a link to the github repository as well, so you can see the entire program: https://github.com/Codecademy/learn-cpp/tree/master/8-references-and-pointers/bleep

Comment: That seems like a good and easy way to go out of bounds ... I mean, if `i == text.size() - N`, and `word.size() > N` then `text[i+j]` is out of bounds and you have UB. (`N` can be any value `>0`)

Comment: You're not comparing indexes, you're comparing actual values in the vectors. And you have to think about the case when `i + j >= text.size()`.

Comment: As for the actual `i + j` operation, it's normal arithmetic. You can add any two values together and use as index. For example, assuming that `text.size() > 8` then `text[2 + 6]` will be perfectly valid.

Comment: `text.find(word)` would seem simpler

Answer (score 0):

Since you're learning, the easiest way to figure this out is to write out exactly what is happening. Take `text=="Hello, World` and `word=="World"`, and work out on paper how this code runs. For what values of `i` and `j` will `match` be incremented?

Comment: I did this. I understand now. Thank you for telling me what I should've done from the start ha. I appreciate it.